# Remove access for unknown devices in account activity

Tags: google-account, security, account-management

Why can't I remove a device off my Google account activity that is not one of my devices?

Comment: Where are you going/what steps are you using to try to remove the device?

Comment: I log in Google - My Account - My Account Activity - Devices .... But once in there there is one particular device I do not recognize and it does not give me the option to Remove. Why could this be happening? No one in my household has a Mac Book, what's even more odd the MacBook is running Linux OS

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: Not a question...But a reply to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity You can remove unknown devices from there.